How to linearize first order ODE
I want to linearize the first order ODE, given as:
\begin{equation}
 f' + \frac{f^2}{a} + \frac{f}{2a} - \frac{3}{2a} =0\,,
\end{equation}
The solution should be $f(a)=1$. But when I just drop the $f^2$ term, the solution becomes $3$. I am not sure which method to use...thanks.

It's worth noting that this particular nonlinear ODE does have a closed-form solution. (The easiest way to see this is to consider $a$ as a function of $f$, which yields a linear ODE for $a(f)$.)

What are you linearizing around? And what is small? If I had to guess, I would assume that you're trying to linearize around the equilibrium $f \equiv 1$, to estimate the solution to some IVP with $f(a_0)$ close to but different from $1$. But this is not how you find the equilibrium $f \equiv 1$ in the first place. The other possibility that comes to mind is that $a$ is just a parameter and you're trying to linearize around $a=0$ with some fixed initial condition. But again, that needs the initial condition to be something other than $f(x_0)=1$, otherwise nothing really happens.

\begin{equation}
 \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{f^2}{a} + \frac{f}{2a} - \frac{3}{2a} =0\quad \text{Condition : }f(a)=1
\end{equation}
This is a Riccati ODE which can solved easily for the general solution.
But no need to solve it because the condition makes the solution obvious :
$$f(x)=1$$
since $f'(x)=0$ and $\frac1a+\frac1{2a}-\frac3{2a}=0$.

Assuming you need to linearize
$$
f' + g(f) = 0
$$
around $f_0(x)$ we have
$$
f' + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\right)_{f=f_0}(f-f_0) + O(|f-f_0|^2)=0
$$
so we follow with
$$
f' + \left(\frac{2f_0}{a}+\frac{1}{2a}\right)(f-f_0) =0
$$
making now $f_0(x) = 1$ and solving for $f(a) = 1$ we obtain $f(x) = 1$
